# Retaining the bottom corner of shape using Inline SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I have this sample CSS below:

```
clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 60px), calc(100% - 40px) 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
```

what this does is it fills the container div and retaining the slanted cutout at the bottom corner of the shape so when the container's height goes up, it would not distort the slanted corner

Is it possible to do the same in inline SVG?

because IE11 and MS Edge version 16 - 17 will be the browser that our web app is going to support which doesn't respect the clip-path CSS property.

Comment: You can specify the values for a couple of presentation attributes via CSS as well, that includes the `d` presentation attribute of a `path` element for example - so that should allow you to still apply `calc()`. (Whether IE and Edge want to play along with that, might be a different question though.)

Comment: how about the percentages? is it possible to set to that particular property?